# How best to handle unfair change in responsibility by manager?

Tags: manager, unprofessional-behavior

I was hired for a project that was in very bad shape. I worked hard and it's about to be complete. I received lots of praise from peers, and went to client demos. Because of my visibility, my manager, who only manages the project, became a little sensitive about it.

The project team overall is low skilled. They made a blunder on the weekend, which I identified and fixed. After two days, I was told that I would be moving to another small project, with one or two months of transition. The technical lead who was responsible for the mess is still on the project, and no one said anything to him after the blunder. My manager is playing favorites. It's not the first time he is doing this.

I'm considering speaking to the Vice President about it, who really likes my work, as well as considering the possibility of finding a new job -- my concern is that once my manager takes away my responsibilities following the transition, I could be easily fired. Of the options I'm considering, how best to approach them?

**After Talking with VP.**
I have a chance to raise this issue to VP. He told me to discuss it with your manager, I won't influence his judgement. I asked him that resources are expensive and we are not able to sell this product, so shift a little bit. But favoring and other team issues, he didn't give it any attention.
Let me tell you, my manager and other guy came to this company via same reference, which is friend with the VP. So it's a favoritism from top to bottom.

I explored by talking to VP, they don't give it a damn about the project/product, they are going to favor the people they want weather they are right or wrong.

**Manager Update:**
I helped another team in a major issue and VP asked me to identify the issue, I did and I also emailed my manager, he called me anger why I solved that issue without his knowledge. So he is getting behind me.

So My options are very narrow here.

Comment: What is the state of the new project?  Is it possible that your boss is moving you to another project that is in very bad shape in hopes that you can shape things up like you did for your current project?

Comment: no that project is very small and not very profitable and it doesn't require senior resources. But I am very qualified and skilled person and I have achieved a lot for this project. I can, but I see that first he would remove me from it and then it would be easy for him to point at me to get fired. But thing is the one who is not beneficial to project, manager is favoring him and giving him the ownership after he regularly disappoints many

Comment: There are just so many ways going to the VP can go wrong.   Any chance you could get transferred to another manager?  And don't quit.  If you decide to move on then find a job first.

Comment: no, unfortunately there is not

Comment: Do you understand the concept that the person it is most important to please in your workplace is your boss?  It is irrelevant if the boss is unfair.

Comment: Being moved out of a failing department may protect you from the axe when they decide that project is not salvageable. You may be misreading a favor as an attack, and the boss may be being unfair in your favor. Are you sure you want to object?

Comment: @keshlam It's a very long life project and there are many clients of it. I have recently given demo and 1 has signed the contract and two are hopefully will buy this product.

Comment: @HLGEM what if his decision can cause company and an individual loss?

Comment: Very long life projects are still sometimes de-emphasized by companies, due to other priorities demanding the resources. Believe me, I understand getting attached to a particular pile of code, but I've made that mistake twice (on the same codebase, actually) and recommend against bothers doing so. Reassignment -- especially if you and your current manager don't get along well -  is often not something you want to fight. The company values loyalty to it, not loyalty to a particular product. If the VP really likes your work, you are over thinking this -- take the transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the normal rule of speaking to your manager may not apply.  Your issue is with your manager so going to their boss would be appropriate.

However, you may find yourself in worse shape afterwards.  So go with caution.    On the plus side, upper management should be made aware that the actions of your manager are going to cause them to lose a valuable employee.

I would schedule a meeting with the VP to 'discuss the status of project x'.  When you go express your concerns that your manager is moving you to another project instead of seeing this one through.  You feel wether intentional or not that your manager is threatened by your success.  That is not your intention, express that your intention is to see a successful project and handing it back to the technical lead that created one crisis already that you cleaned up.

Ask that you specifically be allowed to continue managing the current project.

If you feel any sort of retaliatory actions from your manager, go back to the VP tell him what your manager is doing with facts.  Tell your VP that they will lose you if this keeps up.  It's not a threat, but you have options and working for a bad manager is not in your career plan.  Express that you want to stay and want to see success but if you manager continues to act the way he/she is you cannot do that here.

Comment: Thanks and I am also looking into following this approach because this decision is bad for the project and the company and the time and money they have invested in me.

Comment: I talked to VP, he told me to talk to manager, he can't do anything and influence his decision, it's his call.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that your manager does not like you is reason alone to look for a new job, just to have options in case things work against you.

In most cases, management wants you to follow the chain of command, rather than go around your manager to the VP level. The VP may really like your work, but at the same time may not appreciate the end-run, and probably doesn't have time to address your specific concerns. Going to the VP directly will only give your manager more reasons to dislike you.

If the project team is as bad as you say, your absence will start to hurt them, and it will be obvious where the issues are. While you explore your other options outside the company, I would continue to work hard, do good work, and make your other projects successful.

Comment: Thanks @mcknz, I really appreciate that, I am looking for the new job. If I talk to VP, It would make no difference regarding my managers in-appropriate decision and not liking me. He has already done what he could do to me. What is your take on that?

Comment: @Vicky - get over it, it is not an inappropriate decision just because it wasn't the decision you wanted him to make (people are moved to other projects all the time, sometimes to better ones and sometimes to ones we don't want to work on) and it was his decision to make not yours.

Comment: @vicky - that's really your call, but if this person is still your manager and responsible for evaluating your performance and making compensation decisions, I would not recommend bringing your concerns to the VP. If this person is no longer your manager, then it probably doesn't matter as much.

Comment: Projects can go on for months without people realizing how bad things are. Especially if what they're used to is for projects to be bad. It's like having a sore back--you don't even realize how sore it is until you get treatment and it's fixed. I wouldn't count on problems' becoming obvious jut because Vicky isn't there.